# How to group like numbers using c++

Tags: c++, math, random

So I have written a program to simulate the sum of 10,000 dice rolls and output the results. Now I need to group together all the duplicate numbers and see how many times each one was rolled.

```
for (int totalrolls = 0; totalrolls < 10000; totalrolls + 1) {
    int dice1 = rand() % 6 + 1;//1st roll
    int dice2 = rand() % 6 + 1;//2nd roll
    int sumtotal = dice1 + dice2;//Sum of the two dice 
    cout << "Sum of dice rolls " << sumtotal << endl;
}
```

Here is the code I have written for the first part. maths is not really my strong suit so I would appreciate any method that can help me solve this problem.

Edit: I'm sure this will make you cry a bit but I'm crap with arrays so I tried something else.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL)); //Required to make the dice rolls random.
    int start; //Variable to start the program
    int dice1 = rand() % 6 + 1;//1st roll
    int dice2 = rand() % 6 + 1;//2nd roll
    int sumtotal = dice1 + dice2;//Sum of the two dice 
    int two = 0;
    int three = 0;
    int four = 0;
    int five = 0;
    int six = 0;
    int seven = 0;
    int eight = 0;
    int nine = 0;
    int ten = 0;
    int eleven = 0;
    int twelve = 0;

cout << "Write start to roll the dice: ";
cin >> start;

for (int totalrolls = 0; totalrolls < 10000; ++totalrolls) {
    int dice1 = rand() % 6 + 1;//1st roll
    int dice2 = rand() % 6 + 1;//2nd roll
    int sumtotal = dice1 + dice2;//Sum of the two dice 
    cout << "Sum of dice rolls " << sumtotal << endl;
}

    if (sumtotal == 2) {
        two++;
    }
    if (sumtotal == 3) {
        three++;
    }
    if (sumtotal == 4) {
        four++;
    }
    if (sumtotal == 5) {
        five++;
    }
    if (sumtotal == 6) {
        six++;
    }
    if (sumtotal == 7) {
        seven++;
    }
    if (sumtotal == 8) {
        eight++;
    }
    if (sumtotal == 9) {
        nine++;
    }
    if (sumtotal == 10) {
        ten++;
    }
    if (sumtotal == 11) {
        eleven++;
    }
    if (sumtotal == 12) {
        twelve++;
    }
    cout << "2: " << two << endl;
    cout << "3: " << three << endl;
    cout << "4: " << four << endl;
    cout << "5: " << five << endl;
    cout << "6: " << six << endl;
    cout << "7: " << seven << endl;
    cout << "8: " << eight << endl;
    cout << "9: " << nine << endl;
    cout << "10: " << ten << endl;
    cout << "11: " << eleven << endl;
    cout << "12: " << twelve << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Now I realise how much of a mess this is now but I'm working on a limited time frame. Anyway it now seems to be quite close to working but it still wont log how many of each number is rolled. ( see picture ) https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZtVE.jpg

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can try something for the second part...

Comment: `totalrolls + 1` does nothing.

Comment: Does it not add + 1 onto the totalroll variable which is what allows it to count to 10000? @BaummitAugen

Comment: @davidsmith1 No, it keeps `totalrolls` unchanged, produces the value `totalrolls + 1` and then discards that. You want something like `++totalrolls`.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I disagree. A map is useful when you need a *sparse* array. In this case, you have a dense array, so it might as well be an actual array (or vector, etc.)

Comment: @JerryCoffin Ah yes.  In this case since we now which numbers will occur we can array type.  Good point.

Comment: You have 2 `sumtotal` and only update `two`-`twelve` variables once and not in the loop

Answer (score 1):

Don't store the individual results, define `unsigned occurences[12] = { 0 };` and when the dices output `n1` and `n2`, do `occurences[n1+n2-1] += 1`.

You can then sum everything:

```
unsigned long long total = 0;
for (int i = 1 ; i <= sizeof(occurences)/sizeof(unsigned) ; ++i) {
    total += i * occurences[i-1];
}
```

---

> Now I need to group together all the duplicate numbers and see how many times each one was rolled.

This way, the solution to your problem is trivial.

Comment: I think OP wants the histogram of the sum of 2 dices. (so a gaussian from 2 to 12 instead of a flat graph from 1 to 6).

Comment: It's C++, why not using container instead of raw array ?

Comment: @Garf365 you could. I won't bother though because I'm lazy.

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to build distribution of dices, which is mapping from dice numbers to number of occurrence. For this purpose any associative(std::map, std::unordered_map) container will be fine.
Logic of container usage will be we following:

```
size_t diceVal = doThrowDice();
++container[diceVal];
```

**update:** as possible dice value is within small domain, you can use array instead of associative container.

```
const int maxDiceVal = 6;
int distribution[maxDiceVal];
memset(distribution,0, sizeof(distribution));
size_t diceVal = doThrowDice();
++distribution[diceVal];
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is only valid for your assumption that you want to filter those dice rolls which are identical.

```
// Stores the grouping of equal dice rolls where dice1==dice2
std::vector<int> group(7,0);

for (int totalrolls = 0; totalrolls < 10000; totalrolls++) {
    int dice1 = rand() % 6 + 1;//1st roll
    int dice2 = rand() % 6 + 1;//2nd roll
    int sumtotal = dice1 + dice2;//Sum of the two dice 
    std::cout << "Sum of dice rolls " << sumtotal << std::endl;
    if (dice1==dice2)
    {
        group[dice1] += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why 5 values in array ? not 6, 'cause dice has 6 possible values and also, values are 1 to 6

Comment: The fill constructor of vector take number of elements, not the maximum index. So if you give '5' as argument to fill constructor, you will have a vector with index from 0 to 4. In your case, you need one of those solutions : replace `group[dice1]` by `group[dice1-1]` or have `std::vector<int> group(7,0);` (to be sure values are 0 initialized)

Comment: Thanks, that's actually a great tip!